# How to convert blob to clob or how to use extractValue function for BLOB in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I tried using BLOB datatype in extractValue() to fetch text in specified XPATH, but its throwing error for BLOB data type where it is working fine for CLOB data type.

So I tried to convert BLOB to CLOB with below logic as got from stackoverflow

```
    create function clobfromblob(p_blob blob) return clob is
      l_clob         clob;
      l_dest_offsset integer := 1;
      l_src_offsset  integer := 1;
      l_lang_context integer := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
      l_warning      integer;

   begin

      if p_blob is null then
         return null;
      end if;

      dbms_lob.createTemporary(lob_loc => l_clob
                              ,cache   => false);

      dbms_lob.converttoclob(dest_lob     => l_clob
                            ,src_blob     => p_blob
                            ,amount       => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize
                            ,dest_offset  => l_dest_offsset
                            ,src_offset   => l_src_offsset
                            ,blob_csid    => dbms_lob.default_csid
                            ,lang_context => l_lang_context
                            ,warning      => l_warning);

      return l_clob;

   end;
```

after using above function I am getting output in unreadable format. Please help in how to convert blob to clob in readable format or how to use extractValue() for BLOB messages

Comment: Can you please show your data and function call. `extractValue` is used for `XMLTYPE` which is neither CLOB nor BLOB.

Comment: How are you storing BLOB data in an XML document?

Comment: Also **what error do you get**? that would be a big clue for us.

Comment: 1. above code is converting from blob to clob and displaying data in this format - ‹ (unreadable format)
Its not allowing me to paste complete data her.

Comment: Found that using JAVA API xml is compressed(GZIPOutputStream) and stored into database by java- new SqlLobValue(compStream, logMsg.length(), lobHandler). How to decompress data?

Comment: Problem solved!!! blob:= utl_compress.lz_uncompress(blob); - This line of code added in function mentioned in question, now it decomressing and then converting to CLOB and am able to use this CLOB in extractValue() to extract value from specified xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Error: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments. 
 Xmltype 's constructor for blob data is expecting two parameters. `xmltype(blob,csid)`

`cisd` - character set ID of the blob data `SELECT NLS_CHARSET_ID('UTF8') csid  FROM DUAL;`

2) ORA-31011: XML parsing failed. ... LPX-00216: invalid character 31 (0x1F) 
It's means that oracle is not able to parse xml generated by clobfromblob. 
`invalid character 31 (0x1F)` 0x1f is asci hex code for US  (Unit Separator). reason of this exception can be wrong encoding during conversion from blob to clob or invalid xml in blob data.

Comment: Yes, just now found that using JAVA API xml is compressed(GZIPOutputStream) and stored into database by java- new SqlLobValue(compStream, logMsg.length(), lobHandler). How to decompress data?

Comment: Problem solved!!! blob:= utl_compress.lz_uncompress(blob);  - This line of code added in function mentioned in question, now it decomressing and then converting to CLOB and am able to use this CLOB in extractValue() to extract value from specified xpath

Answer (score 1):

You can use package OraOpenSource Utils [link](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/oos-utils)
wich contains many functions to work with BLOB/CLOB etc.